# qvalue Result confusing, it is two column?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I used `qvalue` from R the `qvalue` package (bioconductor),and applied it on the pvalues from a `t.test`. Then I wrote the result to a txt file, but I had two columns, one for the pvalues and the other for the qvalues. Why did this happen?

```
PVal<-as.matrix(Pval)
str(PVal)
qobj <- qvalue(PVal)
qwrite(qobj, filename = "my-qvalue-results.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour of the function. It returns both the estimated qvalues and the original pvalues as you can see below (taken from the [vignette](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/qvalue/man/qvalue.pdf)):

> **qvalues**:
> A vector of the estimated q-values (the main quantity of interest)
>
> **pvalues**
> A vector of the original p-values

As a quick example:

```
set.seed(9)
#fake p-values
a <- runif(15)
qvalue(a)

> identical(a, qvalue(a)$pvalues)
[1] TRUE
```

As you can see the pvalues are the same before and after running the `qvalue` function.

You can ignore the p-values column if you have no interest in them. Also, if you just want to ouput the qvalues do:

```
#you should be using write and not qwrite (qwrite doesnt exist)
qwrite(qobj$qvalues, filename = "my-qvalue-results.txt")
```

Comment: @ LyzandeR   Thank you for your reply , i tried the code above , but iam getting error ?  ERROR: The estimated pi0 <= 0. Check that you have valid p-values or use another lambda method.

Comment: @ LyzandeR no the code above that you wrote it as test it produce the error :  ERROR: The estimated pi0 <= 0. Check that you have valid p-values or use another lambda method

Comment: That's weird. `set.seed(10)` produces one value equal to zero :P. Try it again now. `runif` produces random values between 0 and 1. Try it now with `set.seed(9)` and it will work.

Comment: the code qwrite(qobj$qvalues, filename = "my-qvalue-results.txt")   also produce error :     Error in qobj$pi0 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: what is the result of `str(qobj$qvalues)` ?

Comment: I cant find the function `qwrite`. where did you find it? The function should be `write(....` not `qwrite`

Comment: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/qvalue/html/qwrite.html                           it is qwrite

Comment: Yeah I saw it now. You should probably add that in the question so that we dont search for it...